# help with erratic_robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
i am trying to install erratic_robot and i am getting errors-
E: Unable to locate package ros-diamondback-erratic-robot
or after i did
sudo apt-get update
i got this long error-
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-diamondback-erratic-robot : Depends: ros-diamondback-ros (= 1.4.10-s1314988837~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-ros-comm (= 1.4.8-s1314988916~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-robot-model (= 1.4.0-s1315008455~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-common (= 1.4.3-s1315005864~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo (= 1.2.8-s1315019072~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-navigation (= 1.4.2-s1315423226~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-laser-pipeline (= 1.2.0-s1315009845~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-motion-planning-common (= 0.3.6-s1315012421~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.3-s1315532575~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-geometry (= 1.4.2-s1315006035~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-common-msgs (= 1.4.0-s1315005773~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-pr2-simulator (= 1.4.3-s1315534131~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-point-cloud-perception (= 0.5.2-s1315018265~natty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
does any one have an idea what should be done?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42368/help-with-erratic_robot/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-04**:
you have to install it like this: sudo apt-get install ros_fuerte_erratic_robot, and thats all!! good luck!

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-11-05**:
Strange, when i tried your method, I get an error, E: Unable to locate package ros_fuerte_erratic_robot. Does anyone knows where I went wrong?

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2012-11-05**:
The proper command is: "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-erratic-robot", notice the dashes (-) instead of underscores(_).

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-11-05**:
Thanks arebgun! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Diamondback is not supported on Ubuntu 12.04 . If you want to install erractic_robot on 12.04 under Fuerte, try for a package like ros-fuerte-erratic-robot. If that deb doesn't exist, you can try installing from source if that package, but the package may or may not be supported on 12.04 & ROS Fuerte.

UPDATE: erratic_robot is available for 12.04 and ROS Fuerte and is available in the package repositories.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2012-09-14**:
erratic_robot stack is supported in Fuerte and is available in Ubuntu 12.04, there shouldn't be any problems installing it from package repository.

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2012-11-02**:
I can verify this.  I just installed erratic_robot from Fuerte under Ubuntu 12.04 today, and everything seems to work as advertised.